# How to detect forward slash and if condition is satisfied check for Enter Key C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, events, key, enter

I'm working on wpf application which is contained of main `Window.xaml` with `DataGrid` on it and articles inside ofcourse, and I should do next, if user select article and press " / ", than I should let him edit price - *unlock field with price*, and when user is done he should hit enter, and after that I should check is enter hitted so I can update new price for that article.

First of all, this is how I'm checking is  "**/**" pressed because I couldn't fight right OEM for this key, and I'm afraid of what could happen when user changes language on his keyboard, so I did it on this way.

```
 private void Window_PreviewTextInput_1(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Text == "/")
            {

                    if (globalTemp != null)
                    {
                        txtPrice.IsEnabled = true;

                    }
             }

        }
```

After I give oportunity to user to change price, I should update article price on Enter key, so how could I check after this condition `if (e.Text == "/")` is enter also clicked, because as I saw there is no `e.Key` in this `TextCompositionEventArgs e`...

**E D I T :**

Maybe I could simply attach new event here, so in fact I might have two events, first one to detect "/" and to unlock txtPrice, and another one to update it if enter is pressed, so another event might look like this:

```
 private void txtPrice_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
 {
   if (e.Key == Key.Return)
   {
     // UPDATE PRICE HERE 
   }   
}
```

Thanks guys
Cheers

Comment: Did you put a break point in the `KeyDown` event and see what the event key code was when you press the "OEM" forward slash?

Comment: @Abion47 how could I do that? how can I check code of "OEM" Fwd Slash? when I catch if (e.Text == "/") { what I should chek here, for which property to read "OEM" CODE} ?

Comment: @Abion47 check for update of my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handle the `PreviewKeyDown` event to detect ENTER key presses and the `PreviewTextInput` event to detect "/".

After all ENTER is not a character and "/" is not a key so it makes perfect sense to handle both these events separately.

If you want to detect the combined ENTER + "/" key combination you could use a Boolean field that keeps track of whether "/" was pressed right before ENTER was pressed:

```
private bool _slash = false;
private void Window_PreviewTextInput_1(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Text == "/")
    {
        _slash = true;
        e.Handled = true;
        //...
    }
    else
    {
        _slash = false;
    }
}

private void Window_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == System.Windows.Input.Key.Enter && _slash)
    {
        // "/" + ENTER was pressed...
    }
}
```

Comment: That's exactlly what I did, but I'm facing issue, when I unlock field with "/", that character is also written in my field even if I don't want to see it there, because we are talking about price, so I guess I should write somewhere there e.Handled=true; even If I don't have a lot experience with that, and to be honest I dont know what that do,  and  if I do that I will be dissalowed to enter anything in that unlocked field, (just because of that e.Handled=true;).. how can I solve this mate? :/ and I think you don't need Window_PreviewKeyDown event, you should attach it directly to unl. field?

Comment: Set the Handled property of the TextCompositionEventArgs to true only if e.Text equals "/" as per in my edited answer.

Comment: yeah that e.Handled property is very helpful and he did thing, so mate can you give us few words about that from your experience, I need to understand why e.Handled helped us when it was inside first condition, I put it on beggining of my private void Window_PreviewTextInput_1 and I couldn't enter anything in my textbox after that.. so mate please give us few words about that, your work is very nice mate! And I really appreciate it!

Comment: and one more thing, Is it correct to attach KeyDown event to TextBox, because point of this is when user unlocks field, write something in, and when user hit enter while he is focused on that field this event which should update some values should be triggered, so txtPrice_PreviewKeyDown is also allright?

Comment: Please don't ask additional questions in the comments. Setting the Handled property to true causes the tunneling event to be marked as handled which basically means that the other built in event handlers won't handle the event and for example set the Text property of a TextBox. Please refer to the "The Concept of Handled" section in the documentation on MSDN for more information about this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806%28v=vs.110%29.aspx.

Comment: Thank you sir, now I will read it and try to understand it, I don't want to go forward if I don't understand what I'm writing, I did not understand really what you mean when you said  tunneling event but I hope that link you provide me will help me to understand that. Thanks again